# Ajax: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at

Tags: c#, jquery, angularjs, ajax, asp.net-web-api2

I have MVC Web API Service hosted on (two servers)

When i consume it by C# like WebClient and HttpClient it works fine and when i also consume it by Postman it works  and i call it by pasting the service URL in the browser it works fine too but when i consume it by jquery sometimes it works and sometimes doesn't work and get the following error

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at myservice.com (Reason: CORS preflight channel did not succeed).

[The request details from Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E14nG.jpg)

Comment: Did you try installing fiddler and see the response message in depth?

Comment: What is the URL of the website shown in the browser? What is the URL you are trying to access with jquery?

Answer (score 0):

We solved that this way, we registered a PreflightRequestHandler in the WebApiConfig.Register()-Method (right after Route-configuration)

```
config.MessageHandlers.Add(new PreflightRequestsHandler());
```

An this is the implementation of the Handler:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace someNamespace 
{
    public class PreflightRequestsHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if (request.Headers.Contains("Origin") && request.Method.Method.Equals("OPTIONS"))
            {
                var response = new HttpResponseMessage { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK };
                var tsc = new TaskCompletionSource<HttpResponseMessage>();
                tsc.SetResult(response);
                return tsc.Task;
            }

            return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
}
```

You may want to handle Preflight different, but this solved our cors issue, as far as i recall.